# Prometheus Grafana CPU monitoring per NUMA

Tags: grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I have several servers with 2 processors with different number of cores (different models of CPU). OS Ubuntu. Monitoring with Prometheus node exporter.
Is any variants to display in Grafana CPU usage for each processor separately?

Can find only information how to display  cpu utilisation per core not per NUMA